# Rejected push after rebasing and resolving a conflict

Tags: git

Our team works on the "dev" branch.

I have another branch "AddLoggingStorageAccounts" with a single commit on it.

Since the commit happened, the other team members submitted several commits on the "dev" branch.

So I would like to rebase the "AddLoggingStorageAccounts" onto "dev".

Until now I only used merge commits, but now I would like to try a rebase and have read several docs on it.

Below are my commands:

```
# git clone -b AddLoggingStorageAccounts https://..."
# cd c:\repos\work-area
# git branch -a
  * AddLoggingStorageAccounts                                                                                                        
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/dev 
# git rebase origin/dev       
  First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
  Applying: Add diagnostic logging for the storage accounts via ARM template
  .git/rebase-apply/patch:163: trailing whitespace.
  warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
  Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
  M       pipelines/shared-templates/build-infrastructure.yml
  Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
  Auto-merging pipelines/shared-templates/build-infrastructure.yml
  CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in pipelines/shared-templates/build-infrastructure.yml
  error: Failed to merge in the changes.
  hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
  Patch failed at 0001 Add diagnostic logging for the storage accounts via ARM template
  Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
  "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
  You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
  To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

Then I edit the conflicted file pipelines/shared-templates/build-infrastructure.yml in a text editor and fix the stuff around the `<<<<<<` markers.

```
# git add pipelines/shared-templates/build-infrastructure.yml
# git rebase --continue                                                                                                                                      
  Applying: Add diagnostic logging for the storage accounts via ARM template
```

Finally, I try to push my rebased branch "AddLoggingStorageAccounts" but the push is rejected:

```
# git push                                                                                                                                                   To https://...
 ! [rejected]          AddLoggingStorageAccounts -> AddLoggingStorageAccounts (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://...'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I try a pull but get another conflict (why? I just fixed that file):

```
# git pull                                                                                                                                                   Auto-merging pipelines/shared-templates/build-infrastructure.yml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in pipelines/shared-templates/build-infrastructure.yml
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Below is a screenshot illustrating my struggles:

[image: screenshot]

Please help a git newbie to manage his first rebase.

I am using git version 2.24.1.windows.2 on Win 10.

Comment: After the rebase, why did you expect the push to succeed? You've rewritten history. And then when you pull you try to merge the unfixed version, because that's what you'd already pushed, so it'll have the same conflict.

Comment: All right and what is the solution then?

Comment: As suggested below, if you're rewriting history you need to _force_ push, to overwrite the old versions of the commits with the new ones. Your comment there suggests that you're not permitted to force push, so you can't use a rebasing model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there aren't any other developers working on this branch, you can force push with `git push --force-with-lease`.

Comment: Thanks I have tried it, but do not have `the Git 'ForcePush' permission to perform this action` in our Azure Git repo.

Comment: In that case you can't rebase pushed changes. Either rebase before pushing or merge instead.